# R: how to transfer numeric of different length into date time

Tags: r, datetime

I want to transfer a numeric value like "212259" into a datetime format. 
These numbers specifies the hours, minutes and seconds of a day. 
I already used parse_date_time((x), orders="HMS")) or out of the lubridate package: strptime(x = x, format = "%H%M%S"), but my problem is that these  columns could also contain values "1158" if it was early in the day. So there is no character for the hours for example. It could also be just seconds, e.g. (12) for the 12. second of a day. 
Does someone know you I can handle it ? I want to combine these value with the column of the specific day and do some arithmetic on it.

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

Do you require something like this?

```
toTime <- function(value) {
  padded_value = str_pad(value, 6, pad = "0")

  strptime(padded_value, "%H%M%S")
}
```

`str_pad` is from the [stringr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/index.html) package

Answer (score 0):

So assuming that the numerical just cuts of the leading zeros, I would suggest you transform to character and then re-add them. You could use a function to do that, something along the lines of:

```
convert_numeric <- function(x){
  if (nchar(x) == 6) {
    x <- as.character(x)
    return(x)
  } else if (nchar(x) == 4) {
    x <- as.character(paste0("00",x))
    return(x)
  } else if (nchar(x) == 2) {
    x <- as.character(paste0("0000",x))
    return(x)
  }
}
```

Let's say your times vector has the examples you mention in it:

```
times <- c(212259, 1158, 12)
```

You could then use `sapply` to get the right format to use the functions you mention for date-time conversion:

```
char_times <- sapply(times, convert_numeric)
# [1] "212259" "001158" "000012"

strptime(char_times, format = "%H%M%S")
# [1] "2016-11-03 21:22:59 CET" "2016-11-03 00:11:58 CET" "2016-11-03 00:00:12 CET"
```

Comment: Hi,
thanks to your help I found a solution for my problem. 

Thanks a lot m8s!!